# Nutch 2 exclude content-type image from crawling

Tags: nutch

The problem is that there can be images not with the specific image extensions. For example Nutch2 was crawling a page ending with `.ashx` but was still an image.

Is there a way to exclude images using an HTML header filter:`content-type: images/*` or something equivalent but not based on a url pattern (`regex-urlfilter.txt`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by writing a [plugin](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/AboutPlugins) that will extend [URLFilter](http://nutch.apache.org/apidocs/apidocs-1.8/org/apache/nutch/net/URLFilter.html) interface.

In `String filter(String urlString)` method, you can check the url if it has some vague extension then further validate by getting its HTTP header values from the server and check if its content type is an image then return `null` otherwise return the URL. But I doubt that would not be very efficient method since many useless HTTP calls will be generated for this validation purpose only.

Another thing is to just let it be and Nutch will not going to parse and/or index the image anyway.